# Errors when executing queries using engine from sqlalchemy library

Tags: mysql, flask, sqlalchemy, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-run

In my backend Python (Flask), (that is running on Google Cloud if that info helps) after some time of usage (during which connections to MySQL are used and made using sql alchemy engine) following error starts to occur:

> pymysql.err.InterfaceError: (0, '')
>
> at ._execute_command (
> /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py:840 ) at
> .query (
> /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py:557 ) at
> ._query (
> /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py:322 ) at
> .execute (
> /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py:153 ) at
> .on_connect (
> /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/mysqldb.py:165
> ) at .on_connect (
> /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py:705
> ) at .**call** (
> /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/event/attr.py:487 )
> at ._exec_w_sync_on_first_run (
> /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/event/attr.py:479 )
> at .__connect (
> /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py:914 )
> at .get_connection (
> /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py:839 )
> at .checkout (
> /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py:719 )

along with:

> pymysql.err.Error: Already closed
>
> at .close (
> /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py:409 ) at
> .do_close (
> /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py:702
> ) at .do_terminate (
> /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py:699
> ) at ._close_connection (
> /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py:377 )

On backend that is connecting to MySQL there are multiple functions that are sending queries and this is one of them (db connection part is same in all functions)

```
def rec_topic_wise(user_id):
    """
    :param user_id:
    :return:
    """
    print("rec_topic_wise")

    sql_result = None
    try:   
        with engine.begin() as mydb:
            sql_result = mydb.execute(text("SELECT repr FROM users WHERE uid = :uid"), {"uid": user_id})
    except:
        return "null"

    try:
        user_representation = tensor(np.frombuffer(sql_result.fetchone()[0]))
    except:
        print("Error")
        return "null"

    #  fetch a list of all topics representations
    query = "SELECT id, repr FROM topics"
    sql_result = None
    try:
        with engine.begin() as mydb:
            sql_result = mydb.execute(text(query))
    except:
        return "null"

    res = sql_result.fetchall()
    #...
    #...
```

And the engine is constructed in this block of code:

```
def createSQLConnection():
    # create SQLAlchemy connection pool
    with Connector() as connector:
        conn = connector.connect(
            "<Instance connection name>",
            "pymysql",
            user="...",
            password="...",
            db="...",
            ip_type=IPTypes.PUBLIC # IPTypes.PRIVATE for private IP
        )

        # create SQLAlchemy connection pool
        engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
            "mysql+pymysql://", # dialect (types of db) + DBAPI driver + how to locate db
            creator = lambda : conn, # lambda function args : expression
            pool_size=140,
            max_overflow=50,
            pool_recycle=1800
        )
        
        return engine

engine = createSQLConnection()
```

I tried to use engine.begin() instead of engine.connect(), to avoid explicit operations but error still persists

Comment: That error usually is a result of attempting to use a connection that has already been explicitly closed. This is unusual as the connection pool should properly handle keeping connections open. Are errors only being seen after a certain extended period of time?

Comment: @JackWotherspoon Yes errors are occuring after some time of usage, at start it seems to work.